# Apache Flink: How to implement a SourceFunction?

Tags: java, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have implemented a `SourceFunction` that fetches data (a String) from an URL. Then I am doing `keyBy()` of that data and apply a window of 10 minutes. Now the `SourceFunction` is called only once and the windows operate on the data for 10 minutes. How can I get data continously from the `SourceFunction`?

```
DataStream<String> = env.addSource(MySource())   // This runs only once
                        .keyBy(some keyby function)
                        .window(for 10 minutes)  // This runs for 10 minutes for the data obtained once by Source function
                        .process(some process function)
```

I want to run the `SourceFunction` repeatedly in a certain time interval and let window work on the continously fetched data.

Answer (score 3):

Your `SourceFunction`s run() method should be a loop which does a sleep (or whatever other scheduling mechanism) to do the work.

A common pattern is to use some sort of atomic boolean that you set to true when `run` is first called, and gets set to false when `cancel` is called.

So you have something like this in your `run` method:

```
while (running) {
   // fetch some data, can be async
   ctx.collect(data);
   Thread.sleep(period);
}
```

You can do that part however you see fit but the important thing is that you do not exit the `run` method of your `SourceFunction` until you are actually done or you have been cancelled.